# How to merge dataframes keeping order in spark or Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to merge two dataframes but keeping the order.

First dataframe has value:

```
>>> df_branch1.show(10,False)
+------------------------+
|col                     |
+------------------------+
|Sorter_SAMPLE_CUSTOMER  |
|Join_Source_Target      |
|Exp_DetectChanges       |
|Filter_Unchanged_Records|
|Router_UPDATE_INSERT    |
|Seq_Unique_Key          |
+------------------------+
```

Second dataframe has value:

```
>>> df_branch2.show(10,False)
+------------------------+                                                      
|col                     |
+------------------------+
|Sorter_CUSTOMER_MASTER  |
|Join_Source_Target      |
|Exp_DetectChanges       |
|Filter_Unchanged_Records|
|Router_UPDATE_INSERT    |
|Seq_Unique_Key          |
+------------------------+
```

I want to merge the dataframe but keep the order and expect the order to be preserved.

Output expect like:

```
+------------------------+                                                      
|col                     |
+------------------------+
|Sorter_SAMPLE_CUSTOMER  |
|Sorter_CUSTOMER_MASTER  |
|Join_Source_Target      |
|Exp_DetectChanges       |
|Filter_Unchanged_Records|
|Router_UPDATE_INSERT    |
|Seq_Unique_Key          |
+------------------------+
```

Any solution through pyspark or python should do

Comment: I do not believe the answer you have chosen works when data exists that could be duplicate.

Comment: Nowhere do you state the data is all unique.

Comment: The data is unique , On a bigger picture - The problem set was using Spark graphframe -  What the question was a part of the problem , that's why it doesn't make sense to you... Actual question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455277/spark-graphframe-find-hierarchy

Comment: The solution was tried through Spark graphframe , finding all branches and then merge with keeping the order . That's why only unique values are expected in dataframes for each branches .. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Oh, you need to be clearer. Got it. Pls be clearer. Success.

Comment: Yes I have a few clues, although not entirely impressed with graphframes from Spark.

Comment: This was a graph problem , I didn't find any other way to find lineage or connection between multiple source to target with maintaining order ... Too bad we still don't have hierarchical query in Spark 3.0. Thanks for your solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do using a `key` column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# create a key column
d1 = d1.withColumn("key", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
d2 = d2.withColumn("key", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

# concat data
d3 = d1.union(d2)

# sort by key
d3 = d3.orderBy('key').drop('key')

w = Window().partitionBy("col1").orderBy('col1')
d4 = d3.withColumn("key", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
d4 = (d4
     .withColumn("dupe", F.row_number().over(w))
     .where("dupe == 1")
     .orderBy("key")
     .drop(*['key', 'dupe']))

d4.show()

+------------------------+
|col1                    |
+------------------------+
|Sorter_SAMPLE_CUSTOMER  |
|Sorter_CUSTOMER_MASTER  |
|Join_Source_Target      |
|Exp_DetectChanges       |
|Filter_Unchanged_Records|
|Router_UPDATE_INSERT    |
|Seq_Unique_Key          |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks , But I want to keep single copy if the values are same . If I do a distinct the order will change ...Please check the output expected in main thread

Comment: not convinced of the solution. will monp... always give right stuff and the sort order has precedence from 1st table

Comment: @PratikRudra please check the edit, it should work now.

Comment: I am sort of surprised this works. 1) the mono thing at scale? 2) repeating data??? E.g. d1 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4') ], StringType())
d2 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('abc'),('2a'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2b'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2c'),('3c'),('4')   ], StringType())   I get a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses zipWithIndex, not convinced on mono... approach. Have another solution but as pushed for time here it is.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, LongType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4')], StringType())
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('abc'),('2a'),('3'),('4')], StringType())

# Common schema, can make def but pushed for time otherwise
schema = StructType(df1.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index", LongType(), True)])
rdd = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex()
rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda row: tuple(row[0].asDict()[c] for c in schema.fieldNames()[:-1]) + (row[1],))
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema)
df1 = df1.withColumn("t", F.lit(1))
rdd = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex()
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda row: tuple(row[0].asDict()[c] for c in schema.fieldNames()[:-1]) + (row[1],))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema)
df2 = df2.withColumn("t", F.lit(2))

# df1 has all values always to be presented is the assumption, it's about getting the extras from df2 and positioned directly after
# functional solution, may be performance an issue, could do woth collect_list etc. but using SQL here
# Did not consider if less values for T1 vs # of values for T2

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("data1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("data2")

df3 = spark.sql('''select * from data2 d2  
                where exists   
                 (select d1.value from data1 d1
                   where d1.index = d2.index
                     and d1.value <> d2.value)
               ''')

dfRES = df1.union(df3).orderBy("index", "t").drop(*['index', 't'])
dfRES.show(truncate=False)
```

returns with ordering preserved in final DF and no distinct required:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|abc  |
|2    |
|2a   |
|3    |
|4    |
+-----+
```

**UPD**

Although the question is vague, this solution caters for repeating values - if the exist, e.g.:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4') ], StringType())
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('abc'),('2a'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2b'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2c'),('3c'),('4')   ], StringType())
```